# IBM Worklight Application Center iOS unresponsive to touch events

Tags: ios, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

After successfully building and deploying the IBMAppCenter project, when attempting to download the IBM Application Center on iOS devices, there is no response when clicking on the actual installer link.  This occurs on both real devices and through the simulator.  Android application seems to be working just fine.  I've provided a picture here showing some of the errors messages that we're seeing when clicking on 'IBM App Center iOS', as well as provided a subset of them below (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xz9r.jpg):

```
Deprecated attempt to access property 'changedTouches' on a non-TouchEvent object.
Deprecated attempt to access property 'target' on a non-Event object.
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.target.getAttribute')
...
Deprecated attempt to access property 'which' on a non-UIEvent object.
```

- App Center Console version 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730
- IBM Worklight Studio version 6.2.0.1

Any idea what may be causing this, and how we can correct it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using a recent iFix of Worklight 6.2.0.x containing required Dojo fixes in order to add support for `iOS 8` (which you are likely attempting to use the app on).

You can review the following tech note for instructions on downloading and installing the iFix: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538

Comment: Hi Idan.  I'm a bit unclear as to which parts of that link you provided we need to follow.  From the download page, it seems like there are four separate interim fixes available, and one fix pack.  Which of these do we need to grab?  Once we've done so, is there more in-depth documentation on how to actually apply the iFix itself?  "Apply the Worklight Server and Worklight Studio files from interim fix that you downloaded from IBM Fix Central" isn't very clear.  Very new to all of this.  Thanks again.

Comment: As an IBM customer you can access IBM Fix Central. For there, you download the latest available 6.2.0.1 iFix. It sounds like it will e enough for you to download the studio update, install it. And re-build the application. I would also make sure that it will use an updated/fresh instance of the Dojo lib.

Comment: It seems to me that the library needs to be updated in the Application Center Console itself, not the IBMAppCenter project.  Is the source available for this, or does it come pre-built with the Worklight Server installs?

Comment: I believe you may need to update the application center server component as well, as it too is built with Dojo.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for finding documentation regarding how to do that?  I'm having some difficulty finding anything.

Comment: All the components are from the latest ifix for the Worklight server 6.2.  If you have installed AppCenter with Installation Manager, installing the ifix with IM will update the server side of appcenter and will also update the IBMAppCenter project. If you have installed appcenter manually, you have to update the two war files that are installed on your server: applicationcenter.war and appcenterconsole.war. Those two war files are distributed in the ApplicationCenter\console directory of the installation.

Comment: In both cases, you have to recompile the IBMAppCenter worklight project following the instructions in the Knowledge Center.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and comment saying that using the Installation Manager to upgrade the Application Center Console to version `01-20141013-1735` corrected this issue.  Thanks again for your help.