# Worklight 6.0 - Steps to fix IBM App Center for iOS8?

Tags: dojo, ios8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 with December 14th fix.
I am trying to use IBM App Center client for iOS8.

I have seen multiple discussions about this issue:

- [IBM Worklight Application Center iOS unresponsive to touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277847/ibm-worklight-application-center-ios-unresponsive-to-touch-events)
- [IBM App center not working for iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059451/ibm-app-center-not-working-for-ios8)

I copied the project from my server, where the fix is installed, and built for iOS, but when I inspect the mobile App, I can see that the application is using Dojo 1.9.0.

```
> dojo.version.toString();
"1.9.0 (29469)"
```

I can see that the IBM App Center mobile client does not use Dojo Toolkit, but includes a dojo.js file (with a size of 1.2MB).

My question is : What are steps to build IBM App Center for Worklight 6.0, knowing that the fix is installed (Both Worklight studio and server)?

Do I need to manually change dojo.js file with a newer version? if yes, where can I find such file?

Answer (score 0):

The AppCenter installation contains an Application Center Installer application project.
This is a Worklight project with the iPhone environment. The app that is generated from it is the Installer application that you need to install on a device, and from which the user will then install any subsequent applications distributed via Application Center.

Make sure you are using the provided Worklight project; there are no additional changes to be done to to  project (other than using your own bundleId, ...).

It could be that you are missing the Dojo library in your workspace?
You can generate it by creating a new Worklight project and application using the Dojo wizard in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When you received the fix, it contains a new project for IBM app centre.
You need to get this project and import it to your Eclipse Environment and rebuild the IBM app centre (APK and IPA) files.
You have to redeploy these files to IBM app centre console and re-download them on your iOS8 devices.

I believe the iOS8 fix starts from version V6.2, and we have downloaded fix v6.2.0.1.
So, I'm not sure about V6.0.
Please verify with IBM.

Comment: Nothing to verify. As mentioned, all Worklight releases received the iOS8 fix for both App Center and DOjo.